# How to fix Axios get and post Request auto change to option in Vue js

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, firefox, axios

I developed vue-js application. I used axios for api call. in chrome browser all api call are working properly. But in firefox some api call are not working. Its method change to options and type is html.

```
       this.axios
        .post("/login", this.userlog)
        .then(response => {
          this.successLogin(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.errorLogin(error);
        });
```

this is request header in firefox

````
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: http://localhost:8080/view-request/150
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used laravel backend. you should add

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With,  Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

this line in the top of your routes file.Should use separate line.